# How do you change Docker OS Support for a .Net Core Web Application Project?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web Application project where I chose the incorrect OS under the  "Enable Docker Support" checkbox:
[image]

How do I change this for an existing project? And to be clear, I want to target linux, not "Switch to Windows Containers..." in docker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This turned out to be easy, and I did it through editing the csproj file: Changed `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>` to `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>` and reload.

I am still not sure where you would do this from Visual Studio (if it possible).

Comment: When doing this on later versions of VS (e.g., 2019), it will detect that change in the .csproj file and prompt you to further change your project's OS support to reflect that change. Apparently there is more to it than just changing the project file, but it appears VS is able to handle that for you.

Answer (score 2):

If only one project is there in the solution, I would delete the project associated with docker-compose.dcproj and Dockerfile inside the API project. After that I would right click and again add docker support to that project.

This would create new dockerfile with linux base image.

And new dcproj will have linux mentioned

```
<DockerTargetOS>Linux</DockerTargetOS>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I am using a .Net Core 3.1 API project and just editing the project file didn't work. I also had to indicate that the docker image was different. This is what I did:

- On the Solution Explorer, Right-click the project, select "Unload"
- Right-click the project, and edit it (The project file can also be edited outside. Even Right click, Add, Docker support worked once)
- As mentioned by others, change:

```xml
<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
```

To:

```xml
<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
```

(Only change "Windows" to "Linux")

- Change the image name. Edit the file called "Dockerfile". Change:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
```

To:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
```

I also changed the build name accordingly. Changed:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
```

To:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
```

The image names may be different. Just make sure to change the Windows image to the Linux image.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core, there are two options for adding Docker support via the tooling. Open the project in Visual Studio, and choose one of the following options:

- Select Docker Support from the Project menu.
- Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select Add > Docker Support.

you should see a windows like this

[image]

And select your desired OS.

You can find more info [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.2#add-a-project-to-a-docker-container)

Comment: The question is how to change the OS after it has already been added, not how to add it.