# Your Docker server host is configured for 'Linux', however your project targets 'Windows' .Net 6

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, .net-6.0, docker-machine

I have created the .net core web api in Visual studio 2022 with docker enabled with selected OS as Windows. After building the code using Docker i am getting **"Your Docker server host is configured for 'Linux', however your project targets 'Windows'"**

Below is my docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ApacheKafka.Producer/ApacheKafka.Producer.csproj", "ApacheKafka.Producer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ApacheKafka.Producer/ApacheKafka.Producer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ApacheKafka.Producer"
RUN dotnet build "ApacheKafka.Producer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ApacheKafka.Producer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish 
/p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApacheKafka.Producer.dll"]
```

In Container.targets its pointing to Windows OS

```
<DockerDefaultTargetOS Condition="'$(DockerDefaultTargetOS)' == 
''">Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
```

Comment: Either you or your computer *misinforms* in this post - "Your Docker server host is configured for 'Linux'", "selected OS as Windows" - make sure the non-metal one knows what they are saying... Please [edit] post to align those statements.

Comment: I would think because your docker image is linux based, when you are building for a windows based OS. Either change the docker container to a windows server based image (see here:  https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/) or change your application target to linux

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `Container.targets`, you are targeting your container type to Windows:

```
<DockerDefaultTargetOS Condition="'$(DockerDefaultTargetOS)' == 
''">Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
```

However, your Docker instance is probably configured to host Linux containers. Either you should do one of the following:

- Change `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>` to Linux (be sure that your container runs appropriately)
- Configure Docker instance to Windows

## To change Docker Container Type to Windows Using Docker Desktop

Here is a link to the Docker documentation outlining how to configure Docker using Docker Desktop:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/settings/windows/

An easy way to switch container types is:

1. Right-click Docker icon in your System Tray
2. Click the `Switch to Windows Containers...` button

## Relevant Links

[How do you change Docker OS Support for a .Net Core Web Application Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502554/how-do-you-change-docker-os-support-for-a-net-core-web-application-project)